# Can end user write data back to database?

Tags: jasper-reports

Is it possible to allow a JasperReports/JasperReports Server end user to write data back to the source database?  For example, if a user is viewing a report that lists customer information, could the report be designed to allow the user to edit or write to a database field, such as a "Notes" field?

Comment: I don't know anything about jasper reports but in general a report is a static view of data. It is not a front end. What you are describing is not a report but perhaps a certain view of the data in an application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the answer to this is no - it's a reporting tool. If you have Jasperserver embedded into your web app you could have an html form which allows writing to the db and you may be able to link this to a report manually. If you really wanted to hack something together you could probably use a hyperlink to the backend and pass the note in as a parameter but this isn't what the tool is designed to do.